# onLoad issue with Mobile Safari, Chrome and Windows Safari

Tags: javascript, html, browser, safari, onload

I'm trying to embed a part of html to a website via DOM manipulation. So I first load the css, then load the HTML. Here's my code;

```
function load_css () {
     var css_file = document.createElement("link");
     css_file.rel = "stylesheet";
     css_file.type = "text/css";
     css_file.href = "http://domain/path/to/css";
     if (css_file.readyState) {
         css_file.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (css_file.readyState === "loaded" || css_file.readyState === "complete") {
                  css_file.onreadystatechange = null;
                  load_module();//ajax call to embed html
              }
         };
     } else {
         css_file.onload = function () {
            load_module();//ajax call to embed html
         };
     }
     document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css_file);
 }
```

This works perfectly on IE8+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera (Linux,Mac,Windows), Safari (Mac, iPad). But it doesn't work on Safari (Windows, iPhone) and Chrome (Android).

The alternate solution is to load html without waiting for css file but I don't want users to experience synchronization problem between css file and html (unstyled html turning into styled one).

What's the best practice to make this work in Safari (Windows, iPhone) and Chrome (Android) ?

Comment: If you use WebView in adroid, it is using html pages as a web-service and pre-cache after load html source. It does not provide dynamic js file loading, i havent try dynamically load css but i tried load js dynamically, it does not worked.

Comment: No it's not a WebView. I refer to the browser @erhan .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only crossbrowser solution for this issue seems to check the document.styleSheets array to see if css has been loaded or not in an interval and set flags. So the solution is is;

```
var module_loaded=false;
function load_css () {
    var css_link = "domain/path/css"
    var css_file = document.createElement("link");
    css_file.rel = "stylesheet";
    css_file.type = "text/css";
    css_file.href = css_link;
    var loaded = false;
    if (css_file.readyState) {
        css_file.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (css_file.readyState === "loaded" || css_file.readyState === "complete") {
                css_file.onreadystatechange = null;
                loaded = true;
                load_module();
            }
        };
    } else {
        css_file.onload = function () {
            loaded = true;
            load_module();
        };
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(css_file);
    var ti = setInterval(function() {
        if (module_loaded) {
            loaded = true;
            clearInterval(ti);
        }
        if (!loaded) {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
                if (document.styleSheets[i].href == css_link) {
                    loaded = true;
                    clearInterval(ti);
                    load_module();
                }
            }
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

I set module_loaded to true if load_module() function is called.